# How to view multiple events with bot.wait_for?

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord, pycord

I want to listen for many events with `bot.wait_for` and not a single event. First event blocks the second one when I arrange them back to back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
done, pending = await asyncio.wait([
                    bot.loop.create_task(bot.wait_for('message')),
                    bot.loop.create_task(bot.wait_for('reaction_add'))
                ], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

try:
    stuff = done.pop().result()
except ...:
    # If the first finished task died for any reason,
    # the exception will be replayed here.
for future in done:
    # If any exception happened in any other done tasks
    # we don't care about the exception, but don't want the noise of
    # non-retrieved exceptions
    future.exception()

for future in pending:
    future.cancel()  # we don't need these anymore
```